# How to find which data have the longest decimal places in impala

Tags: bigdata, decimal, rounding, impala

I have a column stored in decimal(28, 7). How do I know which data have the longest decimal places in impala?

```
For example:
0.0000001 -> 7 decimal places
0.0100000 -> 2 decimal places
0.1000000 -> 1 decimal places
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below SQL

```
length(substr( Rtrim(cast(0.0100000  as string),'0'),instr( Rtrim(cast(0.0100000  as string),'0'),'.')+1)
) len
```

`rtrim` - is used to remove trailing 0s from the data.
`instr` - is used to locate position of '.'.
`substr` - is used to cut strings after position of '.'.

sample SQL-

```
SELECT length(substr( Rtrim(cast(0.0100000  as string),'0'),instr( Rtrim(cast(0.0100000  as string),'0'),'.')+1)
) len
```